# How to lock file in Xcode8?

Tags: ios, xcode, locking

[image]

See, I want to lock my code, How do this?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843033/lock-file-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 6):

It's same with Xcode 7 or early.
* Select your file and find the Full Path in Xcode, then open it in Finder.

[image]

- Get Info and checked the `Locked`.

[image]

- Last, check the file in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you, pictures could guide me through the operation, my English is so bad!

Answer (score 2):

To lock file is possible with the Finder, it is much more troublesome when you need to lock multiple files. The long way now involves right clicking the file in the Project Navigator and selecting Show In Finder. Using Get Info (Cmd-I) will allow you to select Locked. When you do this, the lock symbol will appear in the top-right corner of the source editor, which you can click to Unlock the file.